# Kendo UI server filtering in Openedge ABL

Tags: kendo-ui, progress-4gl, openedge

I was wondering if anyone has been able to come up with a good way to implement server filtering from Kendo UI widgets in Openedge. We have currently got an issue where our existing code Base prevents use of PAS or JSDO.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you somehow post an example of what kind of request the filtering will produce? If done by ajax you can get it from your browsers developer tools. Typically the Network tab/area.

Comment: Jens, a sample request is on slide 46 of the presentation in my reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given a presentation on using Kendo UI with WebSpeed at a number of conferences last year:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2749528/2015%20Kendo%20UI%20with%20WebSpeed.pdf

Slide 46 shows a sample URI that a Kendo UI component would issue to the backend. You'll just have to translate that into an ABL query string.

This is a part of how we handle the query selection. oListQueryExpression is an object that we use for building queries. But you could also create a WHERE clause straight away.

The WebUtilities is just a static class that provides access to functions like get-field.

```
        REPEAT:
        ASSIGN cFilterField    = WebUtilities:GetField (SUBSTITUTE ("filter[filters][&1][field]":U, i))
               cFilterOperator = WebUtilities:GetField (SUBSTITUTE ("filter[filters][&1][operator]":U, i))
               cFilterValue    = WebUtilities:GetField (SUBSTITUTE ("filter[filters][&1][value]":U, i)).

        IF cFilterField > "":U THEN . ELSE LEAVE .

        CASE cFilterOperator:
            WHEN "eq":U THEN
                oListQueryExpression:Add (NEW BufferFieldName (THIS-OBJECT:EntityTable, cFilterField),
                                          OperatorEnum:EQ,
                                          NEW CharacterHolder (cFilterValue)) .
            WHEN "neq":U THEN
                oListQueryExpression:Add (NEW BufferFieldName (THIS-OBJECT:EntityTable, cFilterField),
                                          OperatorEnum:NE,
                                          NEW CharacterHolder (cFilterValue)) .
            WHEN "startswith":U THEN
                oListQueryExpression:Add (NEW BufferFieldName (THIS-OBJECT:EntityTable, cFilterField),
                                          OperatorEnum:Begins,
                                          NEW CharacterHolder (cFilterValue)) .
            WHEN "contains":U THEN
                oListQueryExpression:Add (NEW BufferFieldName (THIS-OBJECT:EntityTable, cFilterField),
                                          OperatorEnum:Matches,
                                          NEW CharacterHolder ("*":U + cFilterValue + "*":U)) .
            WHEN "endswith":U THEN
                oListQueryExpression:Add (NEW BufferFieldName (THIS-OBJECT:EntityTable, cFilterField),
                                          OperatorEnum:Matches,
                                          NEW CharacterHolder (cFilterValue + "*":U)) .
        END CASE .

        ASSIGN i = i + 1 .
    END.
```

I'm not too familiar with the API's that pscript provides. But I know that there are WebSpeed frameworks available that integrate with other frameworks with ease.

Comment: I had been attempting to parse the data into a query string but it seem's like it could get messy rather quickly.

Comment: Messy is a vague term. Are you seeing any specific issues? The JSDO that you mention in your initial post does not do anything else (in JavaScript, not in ABL).

Comment: I think the issue we are having is knowing all of the various thing's that we are going to have to use to delimit and parse the query string that is provided.

Comment: Are you using WebSpeed or the rest adapter on the backend? Which release of OpenEdge?

Comment: Web Speed with ps:escript and version 11.5

Comment: Added a bit of our source code to my initial reply. You'll just have to translate that to psescript.

Comment: Thanks I think I've finally got something similar working.